# How to use no fill for background color of a excel cell using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0

With this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I'm opening the excel and after I'm setting the color of the first cell to transparent like this:

```
xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1");
xlRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

The problem is that it puts white and the "borders" disappear. I want to put the "No Fill" option and it's not working.

I've also tried this:

```
xlRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
```

but then it changed the cell color to black.

---

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that you want to achieve the same state as a cell's initial state (in a new worksheet), use this:

```
xlRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
xlRange.Interior.Pattern = Excel.Constants.xlNone;
xlRange.Interior.TintAndShade = 0;
xlRange.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0;
```

Comment: It worked as well but I used the @Geoff answer because it's just one command.

Comment: For dropdown menu cells, this is the only way. @Geoff's method will result in a pure black cell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is just partly related to this question; but I noticed by using

`xlRange.Interior.Pattern = Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternNone;;`

Also all cell fill color disappears. This is not the case when using:

`xlRange.Interior.Pattern = Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternAutomatic;`

I was searching for this and came upon this question, so I add this for extra info.